# Как понять правильна ли структура приложения или нет?

Tags: java, android

Дело в том, что я написал несколько приложений. И написал на основе максимально имеющихся знаний.

Так вот, как теперь понять

- правильно ли я спроектировал?
- правильно ли распределил классы?
- как можно еще улучшить качество кода, читабельность?

Хоть и корректно программа работает, но мне все равно кажется что мой код оставляет желать лучшего!

Прошу помочь, обширным ответом и еще, может есть форумы где могут просмотреть коды и так далее.

Comment: Почитайте про SOLID, DRY, KISS. отрефакторите код согласно всем извесным вам парадигмам и будет вам счастье

Comment: 1. правильно для вашего уровня. 2. правильно для вашего уровня. 3. дать посмотреть другим. правильность работы можно проверить тестами.

Comment: Насчет 3-го хотелось бы спросить. Вот я например залью на Гитхаб, буду часто Пущить. Но кто мне даст совет там?

Comment: никто. поэтому вам надо вписаться в чужой проект. лучше в несколько.

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая идея

Comment: Если хорошо продаётся, то всё сделано правильно, какова бы ни была структура:)

Comment: Почитайте про [Clean Architecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture).